# Print method of jquery is not show color on print screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've searched a lot on the net for open print screen on browser using jQuery - I find one solution, but the problem is when I click on button at that time it opens print screen of the browser (same as a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> press).

In that screen I don't see the color that I show in my web page. It means the design has changed.

Below is my code that I used.

```
<div class="print_link_box">
    <a href="javascript::void(0)" onclick="window.print()" class="print_link"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Print this page</a>
</div>
```

I use `onclick="window.print()"` function for open print screen popup.

Is there any solution for this problem, print screen show me same as a webpage color, font size, text wise?

Answer (score 0):

In these cases you can use from jQuery plugin that do print and have ability to add Style sheets to your print screen.

I am using  [jQuery Print Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery.print)  for these works

Also you can define special print.css and pass that with stylesheet argument.

Comment: Thanks for help, i use that plugin but issue is same my web page color is not show after ciick on print button . can you help me or give me code ?